# Autocomplete source get via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working right now on autocomplete. What I need to do is change the source of autocomplete, I need to connect my ajax to get the value from database. How I can connect my this script below on my current script? Help please I'm really stuck on this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "iran", "Scheme"];
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(data, { mustMatch: true });
});
$('input#autocomplete').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    $("#result").html(!data ? "No match found!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).search();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#D6D6FF");
});
</script>
```

Here's my current code

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: 'autocomplete.php?'
});
});
function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php?selected='+val
    });
}

<select id="main" name="main" onchange="changeAutoComplete(this.value)">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
```

**Autocomplete**

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["term"]);
    $selected = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["selected"]);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' AND cat_code='$selected' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        $str = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $str[] = $row['item'];
        }
        echo json_encode($str);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try change this :

```
function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php?selected='+val
    });
}
```

into this :

```
function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete("option", "source", "autocomplete.php?selected=" + val);
}
```

the idea is you only need to change to `source` option of the `autocomplete`, instead of re-initializing the whole thing

Comment: not working. My current code works fine, what I need is how I can connect my current code to the script on top with onkeyup event?